# How to fix Android Studio terminal to be same as linux terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnupg

I have recently installed Android Studio on my linux machine. It's terminal shell was set to `\bin\sh`, which starts something like this:

```
sh@5.1~
```

So, I changed the shell to `\bin\bash`. And, now, when I launch the terminal, it looks similar to how linux's terminal looks:

```
username@computername:~$
```

So, I thought everything is set now. But, when I tried to use `gpg`, I noticed some issues:

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

Linux terminal succeeds. But, Android Studio terminal fails with:

```
gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No pinentry
```

For `which gpg` & `gpg --version` commands:

Android Studio terminal says:

```
/app/bin/gpg
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.8.9
```

Linux terminal says:

```
/usr/bin/gpg
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: does `locate gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`  find a conf for EACH of these 2 versions of gpg? If so check each if the dir to pinentry is there. the android version probably does not :)

Comment: @Rinzwind You're right, should I just copy the conf file? Or, can I somehow change Android IDE to use `gpg` from `/usr/bin/`. I am facing same issue with `git` & `ffmpeg`. Both of them have different versions in both terminals.

Comment: so I guessed it correctly? :D 1 possible option: copy the one in app to a backup name and the create a symlink to the one in bin?  make it an answer and you can earn some rep :=) copying the conf file over will work too. might need to reload pgp (or reboot)

Comment: @Rinzwind Hi, I am sorry to be a trouble here. But, `/app` folder is only available in AndroidStudio's terminal. Linux file-manager and terminal do not show any `/app` folder. If I try to rename `git` file in `/app/bin/` using `mv`, it says that file-system is read-only. If I install a new program in linux's terminal, it is not found in AndroidStudio's terminal unless I install it in this terminal as well, a duplicate instalation.